# Extra div wrapper in map function

Tags: arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

i need to create extra div wrapper for second and third element in React

I use  a map function and i dont know how to fix it.
Here is a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/ojz6lvqnp6

And here is a what i need to achive
[image: What i need to achieve]

Another screen:
[image: Another screen]

Comment: An image of your code constitutes poor formatting and is liable to downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code in your render method to

```
 if (index !== 0) {
    return (
      <div key={index} className="second_wrapper">
        <h1 >{index}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  } else ....
```

EDIT:

You would need to change your code to :

```
render() {
const { members } = this.state;
return (
  <div>
    <div className="first_wrapper">
      <h1 key={0}>{members[0].name}</h1>
    </div>
    <div className="second_wrapper">
      {members.map((m, i) => {
        if (i > 0) return <h1 key={i}>{m.name}</h1>;
      })}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

}

The [new sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/x9zo9ym3np)

Comment: it is not solution for my because i need to have only one wrapper name second wrapper and inside of it i need have two obj of array

Comment: Ok. If i understand you correctly, the first element needs to be in div with class first_wrapper and all the other elements need to be in div with class second_wrapper?

Comment: @Pio you just deleted your comment stating that this answer does what you want.

Comment: @palsrealm thanks for your time and solution but its not exacly what i need it is a very small snipet of code in sandbox.
I get a data from Api and i need loop all behevior.
When we have for example 6 obj in our arr the bahaviour must be the same.
First_wrapper -> first obj
Second_wrapper -> second and third obj

First_wrapper -> 4th obj
second_wrapper -> 5th  and 6th obj

Comment: @sn42 i added an anwser it was about good understand of my problem not fix my problem sorry my bad

Comment: @Pio, you should have said so at the beginning. The case you are describing would require you to loop through the array that you receive, using a foreach, instead of a map & then if its the 1st,4th... element, use the first_wrapper heading and for the others use the second_wrapper heading.